# Formato HTML Numero de telefono?

Tags: html, angular

Necesito que al ingresar un número de teléfono en un campo de texto se divida de la siguiente manera: 999-999-9999 y se muestre en un label.

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza la librería ngx-mask.

Instalación:

```
npm install --save ngx-mask
```

Importar en el módulo principal:

```
import {NgxMaskModule} from 'ngx-mask'

import { IConfig } from 'ngx-mask';
export const options: Partial<IConfig> | (() => Partial<IConfig>) = {};

@NgModule({
  (...)
  imports: [
    NgxMaskModule.forRoot(options)
  ]
  (...)
})
```

Uso directo en el input:

```
<input type='text' mask='{here comes your mask}' >
```

Uso como pipe:

```
<span>{{phone | mask: '(000) 000-0000'}}</span>
```

Documentación: [documentación](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask)

Máscara usando función en ts:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  numero;

   format(value, pattern) {
     pattern = pattern.substring(0,value.length);
    var i = 0,
        v = value.toString();
    this.numero =  pattern.replace(/#/g, _ => v[i++]);
}
}
```

uso:

```
<input type="text" #input (keyup)="format(input.value,'###-###-####')">
{{numero}}
```

Comment: No se podra utilizando una funcion en el ts?

Comment: Sí se puede pero según sea el comportamiento que se desee así incrementa la dificultad en la programación. Si no hay restricción de usar una librería externa lo mejor es hacerlo.

Comment: Realmente tengo restringido utilizar una libreria externa por eso ando buscandolo aser por type script